# How update jekyll pages?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am have installed **Base** knowledge base for my own tutorials and all other info which I need when needed. Since it's nice and should be easy to use i choose for this installation.

All dependencies are installed and the Base default pages are working. But once I add an new page into **_posts/2018-07-13-install-something.md** I can not find these in my knowledge base.

After the post is created you have to re-build the pages right ? The Jekyll was build with the command `jekyll build`. So I tried this but it did not do the trick.

In **_site/account-settings/change-email/index.html** is an example post so i copied the directory and changed it to **_site/account-settings/install-something/** and after this i was able to browse to the page. But once i re-runned **jekyll build** the _site/account-settings/install-something was removed.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
Output of jekyll build

> root@###:/var/www/kb/html# jekyll build Configuration file:
>   /var/www/kb/html/_config.yml
>               Source: /var/www/kb/html
>          Destination: /var/www/kb/html/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
>         Generating...
>                       done in 2.172 seconds.  Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.

**_config.yml**

```
# ----
# Site

title: Base
url: "https://kb.example.com/"
baseurl:
google_analytics_key:
disqus_shortname:
newsletter_action:

# Values for the jekyll-seo-tag gem (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag)
logo: /siteicon.png
description: Knowledge base template for Jekyll.
author:
  name:
  email:
  twitter: # twitter username without the @ symbol
social:
  name: Base Template
  links:
    - https://github.com/CloudCannon/base-jekyll-template

# -----
# Build

timezone: Etc/UTC

permalink: /:categories/:title/

plugins:
  - jekyll-extract-element
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-archives

exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - README.md
  - LICENCE

collections:
  sets:


jekyll-archives:
  enabled: ['categories']

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
  -
    scope:
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
      comments: true
  -
    scope:
      type: "sets"
    values:
      _hide_content: true
  -
    scope:
      path: "index.html"
    values:
      body_class: "show_hero_search"

# -----------
# CloudCannon

social_icons:
  - Facebook
  - Google Plus
  - Instagram
  - LinkedIn
  - Pinterest
  - Tumblr
  - Twitter
  - YouTube
  - Email
  - RSS

types:
  - Document
  - Video

_comments:
```

Comment: What errors do you get when doing `jekyll build`?

Comment: @KevinSmith there are no errors it just builds

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of `_config.yml`, at least `permalink` and `defaults`. And also please provide a link to that template you are using.

Comment: @juzraai added the config file

Comment: Jekyll wipes out `_site` on every rebuild unless you set `keep_files`. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/. Also what's `ls -R _site`

Comment: Did you see your new post if you do `jekyll build --verbose` ?